# reCAPTCHA always returns incorrect-captcha-sol

Tags: javascript, python, recaptcha

I'm trying to validate reCAPTCHA in my Python web application, but I always get `incorrect-captcha-sol` error, although the response is correct. Here's the validation code:

```
data = {
    'privatekey': config.registry.settings['captcha_private_key'],
    'remoteip': ip,
    'challenge': challenge,
    'response': response,
}
request = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify',
                          urllib.urlencode(data))
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
if response.readline() != 'true':
    log.error('Captcha validation error, error_code=%s' % (response.readline()))
    raise httpexceptions.HTTPUnauthorized()
```

In order to get challenge and response values, I use `get_challenge()` and `get_response()` javascript functions and then send the values through AJAX.

Comment: And you can verify that the values of `challenge` and `response` are valid/correct? And that `urllib.urlencode(data)` evaluates as you want?

Comment: @Ian i've printed `challenge` and `response` fields in js and python, they are valid and correct. If I remove or modify other required fields like `remoteip` or `privatekey`, I get other errors, so I assume that `urllib.urlencode(data)` correctly converts the `data` dictionary to string.

Comment: It has to be that the input isn't correct. I just set up the simplest Python server (with CherryPy) and HTML form (with AJAX), and it works just fine (using your code too).

Answer (score 0):

Solved this ussiue. It appears that `QUnit` automated `javascript` tests were somehow interacting with the catpcha which resulted in the `incorrect-captcha-sol` code.